# Question about Tukey post-hoc ANOVA test results

Tags: anova, tukey-hsd-test

I have used a Tukey post-hoc test after seeing that the ANOVA test indicated some significant differences between my groups (A,B,C,D). I am somewhat confused about the results.

[image: Plot and results]

Why, for example, is A significantly different from B (although they are very similar); yet A is NOT significantly different from C and D (even though they are clearly VERY dissimilar)?

Perhaps I do not fully understand the Tukey post-hoc test? If someone can direct me to a decent text on statistical analysis (graduate level), that would be greatly appreciated.

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How large are the four groups? Are the error bars representing standard deviations of individual observations within group or standard errors of group means?

Comment: The error bars represent the standard deviations of each group (A,B,C,D). (Calculated using Excels St.Dev function). The groups are rather small. Only 5 samples in each.